# UISearchDisplayController animate reloadData

Tags: uitableview, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been reading all the documentation about `UISearchDisplayController` and its `delegate` but I can't find any way to animate the table view when the search criteria change.

I'm using these two methods :
[image: UISearchDisplayController methods]

They both return `YES` but still can't find any way to do something similar to :
[image: UITableView Methods]

I don't know if it's important but I'm using an `NSfetchedResultsController` to populate the `UITableView` in the `UISearchDisplayController`

That's it thanks !

Comment: In delegate methods you assign new predicate to your fetchresultscontroller. After search done, you assign predicate to original. There are some helpful tutorials in the web, google for it.

Comment: I tried to change the fetchrequest predicate but that doesn't seem to fire the contentDidChange method of NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: Have you run -performFetchRequest on fetchedResultsController after?

Comment: Yes and it still doesn't call the contentDidChange, but I don't know if it's even supposed to, maybe contentDidChange only gets triggered when content of the current request actually changes.

Comment: Are you sure that contentDidChange wasn't triggered? Do you have any NSLog inside it?

Comment: performFetch does not trigger the FRC delegate methods. Change tracking is done only for changes after the performFetch.

Comment: @Flink YEs I'm sure I DDLogged everywhere with colors and everything.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah that's what I thought, so any Idea ?

Comment: @MartinR I thought she has a problem only with searchDisplayController

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the search string or scope has changed, you assign a new fetch request for the fetched results controller and therefore have to call `performFetch` to get a new result set. `performFetch` resets the state of the controller, and it does not trigger any of the FRC delegate methods.

So the table view has to be updated "manually" after changing the fetch request. In most sample programs, this is done by

- calling `reloadData` on the search table view, or
- returning `YES` from `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` or `shouldReloadTableForSearchScope`.

The effect is the same: The search table view is reloaded without animation.

I don't think there is any built-in/easy method to animate the table view update when the search predicate changes. However, you could try the following (this is just an idea, I did not actually try this myself):

- Before changing the fetch request, make a copy of the old result set:

  ```
  NSArray *oldList = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] copy];
  ```
- Assign the new fetch request to the FRC and call `performFetch`.
- Get the new result set:

  ```
  NSArray *newList = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
  ```
- Do not call `reloadData` on the search table view.
- Compare `oldList` and `newList` to detect new and removed objects. Call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` for the new objects and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` for the removed objects. This can be done by traversing both lists in parallel.
- Return `NO` from `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` or `shouldReloadTableForSearchScope`.

As I said, this is just an idea but I think it could work.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking this much time to help me and for your nice answer :) I was kind of hoping I wouldn't have to do something like that but still is a working solution thank you very much =)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I recently faced this and wanted a solution that would work regardless of how the `NSFetchedResultsController` was initialized. It's based on @martin-r's answer above.

Here's the corresponding gist: https://gist.github.com/stephanecopin/4ad7ed723f9857d96a777d0e7b45d676

```
import CoreData

extension NSFetchedResultsController {
    var predicate: NSPredicate? {
        get {
            return self.fetchRequest.predicate
        }
        set {
            try! self.setPredicate(newValue)
        }
    }

    var sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]? {
        get {
            return self.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors
        }
        set {
            try! self.setSortDescriptors(newValue)
        }
    }

    func setPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate?) throws {
        try self.setPredicate(predicate, sortDescriptors: self.sortDescriptors)
    }

    func setSortDescriptors(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?) throws {
        try self.setPredicate(self.predicate, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors)
    }

    func setPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate?, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?) throws {
        func updateProperties() throws {
            if let cacheName = cacheName {
                NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCacheWithName(cacheName)
            }

            self.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            self.fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
            try self.performFetch()
        }

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            try updateProperties()
            return
        }

        let previousSections = self.sections ?? []
        let previousSectionsCount = previousSections.count
        var previousObjects = Set(self.fetchedObjects as? [NSManagedObject] ?? [])
        var previousIndexPaths: [NSManagedObject: NSIndexPath] = [:]
        previousObjects.forEach {
            previousIndexPaths[$0] = self.indexPathForObject($0)
        }
        try updateProperties()
        let newSections = self.sections ?? []
        let newSectionsCount = newSections.count
        var newObjects = Set(self.fetchedObjects as? [NSManagedObject] ?? [])
        var newIndexPaths: [NSManagedObject: NSIndexPath] = [:]
        newObjects.forEach {
            newIndexPaths[$0] = self.indexPathForObject($0)
        }

        let updatedObjects = newObjects.intersect(previousObjects)
        previousObjects.subtractInPlace(updatedObjects)
        newObjects.subtractInPlace(updatedObjects)

        var moves: [(object: NSManagedObject, fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath)] = []
        updatedObjects.forEach { updatedObject in
            if let previousIndexPath = previousIndexPaths[updatedObject],
                let newIndexPath = newIndexPaths[updatedObject]
            {
                if previousIndexPath != newIndexPath {
                    moves.append((updatedObject, previousIndexPath, newIndexPath))
                }
            }
        }

        if moves.isEmpty && previousObjects.isEmpty && newObjects.isEmpty {
            // Nothing really changed
            return
        }

        delegate.controllerWillChangeContent?(self)

        moves.forEach {
            delegate.controller?(self, didChangeObject: $0.object, atIndexPath: $0.fromIndexPath, forChangeType: .Move, newIndexPath: $0.toIndexPath)
        }

        let sectionDifference = newSectionsCount - previousSectionsCount
        if sectionDifference < 0 {
            (newSectionsCount..<previousSectionsCount).forEach {
                delegate.controller?(self, didChangeSection: previousSections[$0], atIndex: $0, forChangeType: .Delete)
            }
        } else if sectionDifference > 0 {
            (previousSectionsCount..<newSectionsCount).forEach {
                delegate.controller?(self, didChangeSection: newSections[$0], atIndex: $0, forChangeType: .Insert)
            }
        }

        previousObjects.forEach {
            delegate.controller?(self, didChangeObject: $0, atIndexPath: previousIndexPaths[$0], forChangeType: .Delete, newIndexPath: nil)
        }
        newObjects.forEach {
            delegate.controller?(self, didChangeObject: $0, atIndexPath: nil, forChangeType: .Insert, newIndexPath: newIndexPaths[$0])
        }

        delegate.controllerDidChangeContent?(self)
    }
}
```

It exposes 2 properties on the `NSFetchedResultsController`, `predicate` and `sortDescriptors` which mirrors those found in the `fetchRequest`.
When either of these properties are set, the controller will automatically compute changes the changes and send them through the delegate, so hopefully there is no major code changes.
If you don't want animations, you can still directly set `predicate` or `sortDescriptors` on the `fetchRequest` itself.