# Update NSFetchedResultsController fetch request predicate, refresh table with animations?

Tags: ios, core-data

I cannot seem to find this laid out anywhere.

I have what is effectively a search box (though it's using a UITextView, not a search box/controller).

As the user types in words, I want to update the 'suggestions' in the table view below that are pulled from Core Data. These are displayed in a table below using the typical NSFRC setup.

After the user types (and with a delay of .5s) I update the fetch request predicate with their text, and call performFetch again.

What I really want is the new results to animate in, as you would normally see with NSFRC, of course leaving any existing matching rows in place. Currently the only way I get these to update is by calling reloadData on the table.

Is there a way to get what I'm after here?

Comment: There is no built-in method to animate the table view changes after a change of the fetch request. I have suggested a possible solution in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797224/uisearchdisplaycontroller-animate-reloaddata.

Comment: It's not titled very well, so hard to find, but @MartinR did provide a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14801165/287403. Voted to close this.